# Identify the ancient IOT hardware model and find out its driver

Tags: arduino, hardware

Found from the bottom of my gadget box, I am trying to use this board for my hobby project, but I cannot even remember what model it is.

Could anyone help please to identify the model of this board?
Also, where to download its driver as I suppose that I will need the driver to use this board.
[image: board]

So far I know it's from GHI Electronics, brand is Canxtra, I searched "Canxtra Rev 2.1A" but nothing returned.

Comment: why don't you ask this at a GHI electronics forum?

Comment: @jsotola good idea, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a programmable OBD-II tool.

https://docs.ghielectronics.com/hardware/automotive.html

[image]